# Create a cards carousel slider with blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been working with blazor server for some time now but I have not been able to achieve how to create a cards carousel with it. I want to use slick slider in my project. I have downloaded slick and jquery, linked jquery, slick.min.js, slick.js, slick-theme.css and slick.css but nothing seems to work. I've tried looking on the web for some solutions but none of these are clear to understand. I've also done this with html, css and js and it works just fine. Please anyone help me with this because i believe a carousel is a very important component in a website.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace Blogger.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="scrollbar-thin scrollbar-track-transparent scrollbar-thumb-slate-500">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Blogger.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css">
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slick.js"></script>
    <script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is not working for you because you have implemented both the normal and the minified file?

```
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.js"></script>
```